# How do I use cv2.putText to display names above the detected faces?

Tags: python, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE3d7.jpg)I'm using dlib for my image-based face recognition application. How do I use `cv2.putText` to write names above the detected faces?

```
for ( k, face ) in enumerate( face_image ):  

    faceBlob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(face, 1.0 / 255,
    (96, 96), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    embedder.setInput(faceBlob)
    vec = embedder.forward()

    # perform classification to recognize the face
    preds = recognizer.predict_proba(vec)[0]
    j = np.argmax(preds)
    proba = preds[j]
    name = le.classes_[j]
```

Comment: Don't you get some bounding box for the detected faces? Use the `x, y` coordinates from the upper left corner of that box, slightly decrease `y`, and use this point in your `cv2.putText` call. Or what is your actual question here?

Comment: i tried to use cv2.putText the name will overlap each other

Comment: add an example image?

Comment: @Andy_101 added linked to image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE3d7.jpg)

Comment: @HansHirse i use cv2.putText the name will overlap each other

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with the values.

```
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 
    org = (x, y) 
    fontScale = 1 #(try differnt values)
    color = (0, 0, 0) 
    thickness = 2 #(try differnt values)
    image = cv2.putText(img, "TEXT", org, font,  
                       fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try using these*

```
image = cv2.rectangle(webcamFrame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 1)
                    cv2.putText(webcamFrame, 'PUT_YOUR_TEXT', (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (36,255,12), 2)
                    roi_gray = grayImage[y:y+h, x:x+w] 
                    roi_color = webcamFrame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```